# Parsing jmeter results file

Tags: xslt, jmeter

I I am stuck with a problem in Jmeter. Can any one please help me to solve this issue:

I have to develop scripts for automation of  API functional testing using Jmeter. The design is as follows:

1. For each API a thread group is created.
2. Some thread groups have more than one sample request. For example we have to invoke login api before accessing a feature.
3. The thread groups are independent of the other.

I have to generate a report at the thread group level and need to add a pass or fail result. I have tried ant with xslt report. But here, the result is displayed for each sample. I don’t want to include performance statistics like avg response time in my report.

I am searching a lot but could not find the solution. Can you please share any links or help me to achieve the same.

And also how to add a pie chart for jmeter results?

Comment: What do you mean with "at the thread group level"? When exactly is a thread group supposed to pass or fail? Without more information about your setup and your requirements, it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: Hi, I do have assertions added to  samples where ever necessary. Most precisely I am searching for a functional testing report for Jmeter as it supports the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this situation. I have customized [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) to convert XML report generated by Jmeter into other formats like Junit reports.
I grouped samples based on the thread group name.